# How to save custom meta box's data?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to learn something about WordPress plug-in development. Here is my first attemp to write something. This should create an input field on "page" pages to store a custom value.

This is the code I written, but something doesn't work. I can't save my data.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: nw_Page_Gallery
*/

class nw_Page_Gallery {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->add_meta_boxes();
    }

    public function add_meta_boxes(){
        add_action("add_meta_boxes", array($this, "add_meta_box_images"));
    }

    public function add_meta_box_images(){
        add_meta_box("nw_page_image", "Sfondo pagina", array($this, "add_image_box"), "page");
    }

    public function add_image_box($post){
        $back_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nw_page_image', true);
        echo "Il valore è".$back_url;
        ?>
        <label>Lenght:</label> 
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="nw_page_image" id="nw_page_image" value="<?php echo $back_url; ?>" />
        <?php

        add_action("save_post", function($id){
            if(isset($_POST['nw_page_image'])){
                    update_post_meta(
                        $id,
                        'nw_page_image',
                        strip_tags($_POST['nw_page_image'])
                    );
                }
        });
    }
}

add_action("admin_init", function(){
    $PG = new nw_Page_Gallery();
});
```

Can someone tells me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing your `add_action("save_post",` in the last place it should be...

That belongs to the `__construct`, or as you're doing:

```
public function add_meta_boxes(){
    add_action("add_meta_boxes", array($this, "add_meta_box_images"));
    add_action("save_post", function($id){
        if(isset($_POST['nw_page_image'])){
                update_post_meta(
                    $id,
                    'nw_page_image',
                    strip_tags($_POST['nw_page_image'])
                );
            }
    });
}
```

Note that you are hooking into `save_post` without checking for a bunch of things (if it is revision, if doing autosave) and *more problematic*, without security checks: [`wp_nonce_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field).

You can find plenty of good examples at WordPress Answers, check [this search query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2badd_meta_box%20%2bsave_post%20is%3aanswer).